# New image on thumbnail hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

Hey all, I'm trying to implement something where I have 2 thumbnail pictures underneath 1 large image. I would like the large image to change to another picture when you hover over the thumbnail. Is there a script, or tutorial out there for this? Possibly jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery would rock this. [Here](http://www.web-design-talk.co.uk/200/jquery-hover-effect-image-gallery-for-ecommerce/) is a tutorial that does something similar. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

U can do it with hover function

CSS CODE:

```
.nav {
   background:url(images/3.png) no-repeat;
}

.nav_hover {
   background:url(images/4.png) no-repeat;
}
```

JQUERY CODE:

```
$('.nav').hover( 
function(){
   $(this).addClass('nav_hover');
}, 
function(){
   $(this).removeClass('nav_hover');
}
);
```

HTML Code:

```
// Call  class CSS Script to element
```

Check it

Comment: You should have included the html so that anyone wanting to studying this code would know where .nav and  'nav_hover' was used in the body script. For me the answer was not fully useful.